# What causes the different NaN behavior when compiling `_mm_ucomilt_ss` intrinsic?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, x86, floating-point-comparison

Can someone explain me why the following code fails for GCC 8.5 with NaNs?

```
bool isfinite_sse42(float num)
{    
    return _mm_ucomilt_ss(_mm_set_ss(std::abs(num)),
                          _mm_set_ss(std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity())) == 1;
}
```

My expectation for GCC 8.5 would be to return false.

The Intel Intrinsics guide for `_mm_ucomilt_ss` says

```cpp
RETURN ( a[31:0] != NaN AND b[31:0] != NaN AND a[31:0] == b[31:0] ) ? 1 : 0
```

i.e., if either `a` or `b` is NaN it returns 0. On assembly level ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nfP3sY9rs)) one can see a `ucomiss abs(x), Infinity` followed by a `setb`.

```
# GCC8.5 -O2  doesn't match documented intrinsic behaviour for NaN
        ucomiss xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC2[rip]
        setb    al
```

Interestingly newer GCCs and Clang swap the comparison from `a < b` to `b > a` and therefore use `seta`. But why does the code with `setb` returns true for NaN and why `seta` returns false for NaN?

Comment: `setb`/`seta` only look at the carry flag which is set to `1` for unordered.

Comment: re: your example on Godbolt: `x < INFINITY` will be true for `-INFINITY`.  That's why `isfinite_builtin` uses `andps` to take the absolute value first.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I removed the `abs` code beforehand. I changed my code example. But the problem still persists.

Comment: @Jester, I sadly don't get the difference. `seta` gives the correct result but `setb` not. Can you please further explain the difference? From the intrinsics description it should return 0 when either operand is NaN. But this is not the case. Why? When looking at the assembly I just saw the difference `seta` vs. `setb` but cannot explain what is happening (maybe it is even unrelated to the issue?).

Comment: Yeah, GCC8.5 seems to be buggy, not implementing the documented semantics of the intrinsic for the NaN case which require either checking PF separately, or doing it as `ucomiss Inf, abs` so the unordered case sets CF the same way as `abs < Inf`.  See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ucomiss#operation or the nicer table in https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fcomi:fcomip:fucomi:fucomip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GCC is buggy before GCC13**, not implementing the documented semantics of the intrinsic for the NaN case which require either checking PF separately, or doing it as `ucomiss Inf, abs` so the unordered case sets CF the same way as `abs < Inf`.

See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ucomiss#operation or the nicer table in https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fcomi:fcomip:fucomi:fucomip .  (All x86 scalar FP compares that set EFLAGS [do it the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188286/why-do-x86-fp-compares-set-cf-like-unsigned-integers-instead-of-using-signed-co), matching historical `fcom` / `fstsw` / `sahf`.)

| Comparison Results | ZF | PF | CF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| left > right | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| left < right | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| left = right | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Unordered | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Notice that CF is set for both the `left < right` and unordered cases, but not for the other two cases.

If you can **arrange things such that you can check for `>` or `>=`, you don't need to `setnp cl` / `and al, cl` to rule out Unordered.**  This is what clang 16 and GCC 13 do to get correct results from `ucomiss inf, abs` / `seta`.

GCC8.5 does the right thing if you write `abs(x) < infinity`, it's only the scalar intrinsic that it doesn't implement properly.  (With plain scalar code, it uses `comiss` instead of `ucomiss`, the only difference being that it will update the FP environment with a #I FP-exception on QNaN as well as SNaN.)

This requires a separate `movss` load instead of a memory source.  But this does let GCC avoid the useless SSE4.1 `insertps` instruction that zeros the high 3 elements of XMM0, which `ucomiss` doesn't read anyway.  Clang sees that and optimizes away that part of `_mm_set_ss(num)` but GCC doesn't. The lack of an efficient way to go from a scalar `float` to a `__m128` with don't-care upper elements is a persistent problem in Intel's intrinsics API that only some compilers manage to optimize around.  (*[How to merge a scalar into a vector without the compiler wasting an instruction zeroing upper elements? Design limitation in Intel's intrinsics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318496/how-to-merge-a-scalar-into-a-vector-without-the-compiler-wasting-an-instruction)*)  A `float` is just the low element of a `__m128`.

Comment: Thanks. Just a side note: GCC has the wrong behavior up to GCC12 https://godbolt.org/z/5e6914jYb

Comment: And `_mm_ucomieq_ss` has the same issue: https://godbolt.org/z/zx1T6z7vT. This time `sete` is used which tests the ZF flag. GCC13 inserts the `jp` instruction as you said "either checking PF separately". But as you also said there is a better solution by checking with `>` or `>=` which is done by the builtin.

Comment: @jerryct: Yeah that's unsurprising, it's the same bug affecting other FP compare predicates. Interesting point that we can optimize the source to `abs >= inf` to allow `seta`, instead of `setnp` / `cmovne` (scalar `==`) or a branch (intrinsic).  https://godbolt.org/z/3dbGso5n1 .  GCC misses that optimization, but it's safe because nothing can ever be larger than inf so we only get the == part.  In asm it allows `seta` to check ZF and CF in one uop.